# Create and Array of read-in Data in R

Tags: arrays, r, list, data-import

I want to analyze 30 files (file1...file30) of csv data in R.
Is it possible to create an array of the separate lists (like a three dimensional array with each list as a 'table) so that I can later use loops to go through the array rather than entering each file separately for analysis?

Thanks!

Stephanie

Comment: Please show some effort and code before people can help to point out your mistakes. Don't expect people to write the full code for you

Answer (score 0):

Get the names of the csv files

```
filenames <- dir("directory/to/csv/files")
```

Now you can construct a list of tables like this

```
data <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)
```

which returns a list where each element contains the content of one file.
Now it is possible to loop through the data like this for example

```
result <- lapply(data, 
                 function(x) {
                   # whatever you want to do with the data
                 })
```